# unable to get expected font in output

Tags: php, html, css, fonts, themes

I am storing my certificate theme in database as a html. my template fonts are weeding fornt. themes looks nice in browser out put . but when i tried to fetch from databse and disply in pdf the normal font output is coming . i am not getting where i am wrong .

code for storing template in databse :

```
 <?php
ob_start();
?>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8" />
    <style type="text/css">
        h1{
            font-family: 'weddingtext_btregular';
            font-weight:200;
            font-size:25px;
        }
        h2{
            font-family: 'weddingtext_btregular';
            font-weight:300;
            font-size:30px;
        }
        .span {
            font-family: cursive;
        }
        .span1 {
            padding-left:20%;
        }
        .span2 {
            padding-left:50%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<?php
// normal output
echo '<img alt="Nimhans Logo" src="img/1.png" width="100%" ; />
      <h1>SL NO. <span class="span">##SLNO##</span></h1>
          <div class="body">
           <center><h1>Institute of National Importance</h1></center>
            <center><h1>Bengaluru - 560 029</h1></center>
              <br>
           <center><h1>Certifies that</h1></center>
           <br>
           <center><h2>##NAME##</h2></center>
           <br>
        <center><h1>has been dulg admitted to the Degreeof</h1>                  </center>

          <br>
           <center><h2>##COURSE##</h2></center>
        <br>
          <center><h1>in recognition of the fulfilment of requirements</h1></center>
          <center><h1>under the statutes of the institute</h1></center>
           <center><h1>##YEAR##</h1></center>
         <br>
           <center><h2>##CLASS##</h2></center>
            <br>
               <h1>##QRCODE## <span class="span1"> Biben under the seal of the Institute</span></h1>
             <br>
                <br>
            <h1>Date:29th November, 2015 <span class="span2"> Director/Dice Chancellor</span></h1>
             ';

// store buffer to variable and turn output buffering offer
$html = ob_get_clean();

echo $html;

include 'configaration/config.php';

$html = mysql_real_escape_string($html);

$dpt_name = "Nursing";
$qry = "INSERT INTO certificate (cert_data,department)
          VALUES ('$html','$dpt_name')";

if (!mysql_query($qry)) {

    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}
?>
```

fetching template from databse and displaying in PDF.

here is my code :

```
$qry1 = "SELECT * FROM certificate WHERE department = '" . $dpt_name . "'";
$result1 = mysql_query($qry1);

if ($result1) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) {

        $template_data = $row["cert_data"];
    }
}
$template_data = str_replace('##NAME##', $std_name, $template_data);
$template_data = str_replace('##FROM##', $join_date, $template_data);
$template_data = str_replace('##NAME##', $std_name, $template_data);
$template_data = str_replace('##TO##', $to, $template_data);

ob_end_clean();

include 'MPDF57/mpdf.php';

$mpdf = error_reporting(E_STRICT);
$mpdf = new mPDF('win-1252', 'A4', '', '', 15, 10, 16, 10, 10, 10);
$mpdf->Bookmark('Start of the document');
$mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
$mpdf->WriteHTML($template_data);
$mpdf->Output();

exit();
```

browser output :

[image: BROWSER OUTPUT]

pdf output images :
[image: PDF out put]

PLEASE HELP ME WHERE I AM WRONG . SORRY FOR MY BAD ENGLISH .

Comment: I guess the font isn't available on the server when it tries to build the PDF so it substitutes the font. I'd suggest trying to install the font on the server.

Comment: @Nayana
Do you have the otf files of the font? Are you importing it prior to use? I don't see anywhere that you've imported it.

Comment: yes. i have included style.css . my style.css contains  
@font-face {
    font-family: 'weddingtext_btregular';
    src: url('ufonts.com_wedding-text-bt_1.eot');
    src: url('ufonts.com_wedding-text-bt_1.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('ufonts.com_wedding-text-bt_1.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('ufonts.com_wedding-text-bt_1.woff') format('woff'),
         url('ufonts.com_wedding-text-bt_1.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('ufonts.com_wedding-text-bt_1.svg#weddingtext_btregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}

Comment: which pdf you r using to generate it??

Comment: then u shud include the fonts in mpdf not in style.css

Comment: wait i will try and get bak to you .

Comment: Meanwhile, you might consider changing your `mysql_*` functions since they are deprecated in PHP5 and were removed in PHP7, you should use `mysqli_` specialized interface or `PDO` class. Also, you could try using [`tcpdf`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tcpdf/files/), based on FPDF as mPDF, but still maintained.

Comment: To generate the pdf with your desired font, try to set font in mpdf. Also refer [here](http://mpdf1.com/manual/index.php?tid=276)

Comment: problem solved . i have included my font in mPDF . now its working . @niranjan . thank you

Comment: @Nayana consider accepting the answer for future users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using font in css. but you should use in mpdf.

```
config_fonts.php // you should add in this page and
```

then it will reflect. And add font files in your `ttfonts` directory.

```
 $this->fontdata = array(
    "name of your font" => array(
        'T' => "Neutra_Display_Thin_Alt.ttf",// path to your font
     )
 );
```

see this [link](http://www.mpdf1.com/forum/discussion/1220/adding-fonts-in-mpdf/p1) for more information.